# Disposing of custom in-memory controls in a form

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, dispose

I have a `Form` (well, my window, which inherits from `Form`), where I want to create some controls once and then reference them throughout the code in this class.

So I create fields:

```
private Label _someCounter;
private Label _someAnotherCounter;
```

I initialize them, use them as I want and it's great.

But I also need to rememeber about **disposing** them and here's the question: how would I do that? I can think of three ways:

1. I write some more code in `Dispose` override method, generated by designer (as designer might in some time overwrite it, I don't like this idea).
2. I found `copmonents` field in a class, which is disposed by genereted `Dispose` override, so I just add those controls to `copmonents` collection, so they are disposed automatically.
3. After all, I am thinking also that, I add them to my interafce after all, so they are added to `component` anyway. So I don't need to do anything.

Comment: Take a look at this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose.
It explains how to implement `IDisposable` and also mentioned how to handle when inheriting a base class that already implements `IDisposable`.

Comment: I think you don't need to do anything. If you add your controls to a controls collection of some container (as you should do to see them) then the container will dispose all its children when it is disposed. You can see that logic in the referencesource at [Control.Dispose method](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,d85b7dd334cd518d)

Comment: Note that it is only the code in the region `#region Windows Form Designer generated code` that is regenerated when building - not the entire Form.designer.cs file, so it's safe to modify the rest of it (including `Dispose(bool disposing)`). But I think Steve is right in his comment.

Comment: @HenrikHansen You should not modify the designer.cs file. Unless you carefully know what you do, such as renaming or changing a type (for example you may want change a label to a checkbox), or if you want to quickly edit controls properties by code, or fix a compile error if your refactoring or other thing somewhere break this file.

Comment: @OlivierRogier: You're really not reading, what I'm writing. Modifying `Dispose(bool disposing)` is perfectly safe, and you should use it, if you have objects in your form, that you want to dispose of manually :-)

Comment: So you know what you do :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so you can create dummy class:

```
public class MyLabel : Label
{
  protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
  {
    base.Dispose(disposing);
  }
}
```

And you can set breakpoint in the `Dispose` method.

Changed fields' type to `MyLabel` and checked whether the method is called and it is called without me explicitly calling them or doing anything.

So the third way is correct - since they are added as `Form` controls, they are getting diposed automatically.

Comment: That's what I assumed but I was too lazy to check. :-)

Comment: @OlivierRogier I think that he does this just to check the assumption that Dispose is called automatically by the Winforms engine. And he has the confirm that it is called automatically.

Comment: @OlivierRogier This code is just to test it and resolve the question, it's not something I will hold on to.

Comment: @Olivier How else could OP verify the assumption made? Can you suggest a better method to verify it?

Comment: Indeed in fact, you're very right. I'm sorry. I am suffering these days and I read too fast. SO takes care of me a bit. I really have to be more careful. So your answer is great. Sorry again. Upvoted.